# Adapter not showing the results

Tags: android, json, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I have a json response for which i have created a adapter to list the json into the view, there is no error in the app, but it is also not showing the results. Here is my adapter class:

```
  package com.JustDine.Infrastructure;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.Filter;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.LinearLayout;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  import com.JustDine.GUI.R;
  import com.JustDine.JSON.Response.RedemptionResult;
  import com.JustDine.JSON.Response.SearchResult;

  public class RedemptionListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RedemptionResult> {
Context context;

private List<RedemptionResult> redemptionResultList = new ArrayList<RedemptionResult>();
//public ArrayList<RedemptionResult> filtered = new ArrayList<RedemptionResult>();
// public boolean isFiltered;
int position;
int textViewResourceId;
ImageLoader imageLoader;

public RedemptionListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<RedemptionResult> redemptionResultList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, redemptionResultList);
    this.context = context;
    this.redemptionResultList = redemptionResultList;
    this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    this.position = position;
    LinearLayout redemptionView;
    RedemptionResult redemptionResult = null;

    redemptionResult = redemptionResultList.get(position);



    if (v == null) {
        redemptionView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(textViewResourceId, redemptionView, true);
    }


    TextView tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.resName);

    tvName.setText(redemptionResult.getName());


    return v;

}
 }
```

Please help, why it is not showing the results.

**Updated: Json response class**

```
 package com.JustDine.JSON.Response;

 import java.util.List;

 import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

 public class RedemptionResultResponse {

@SerializedName("Success")
public boolean Success;

@SerializedName("redemption_partners")
private List<RedemptionResult> getRedemptionPartners;

@SerializedName("denominations")
private List<DenominationsResult> getDenominations;

@SerializedName("errorMessage")
public String errorMessage;

@SerializedName("Tag")
public String Tag;




public List<RedemptionResult> getRedemptionPartners() {
    return getRedemptionPartners;
}

public List<DenominationsResult> getDenominations() {
    return getDenominations;
}

public void setRedemptionPartners(List<RedemptionResult> getRedemptionPartners) {
    this.getRedemptionPartners = getRedemptionPartners;
}

public void setDenominationss(List<DenominationsResult> getDenominations) {
    this.getDenominations = getDenominations;
}

   }
```

and

```
  package com.JustDine.JSON.Response;

  import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

  public class RedemptionResult {
@SerializedName("id")
private String id;

@SerializedName("name")
private String name;


public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Comment: `{
    "Success": true,
    "redemption_partners": {
        "10013": "Ningxia Chinese - (Mirdiff, Dubai)",
       },
    "denominations": [
        50,
        100
    ],
    "errorMessage": "NoError",
    "Tag": "getRedemptionData"
}` my json format..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private ArrayList<ExploreCatgModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<ExploreCatgModel>();
private ExploreCatgModel model;
```

set data into Model class

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            webService = new WebService();
            String result = webService.aboutList();
            if (result != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject
                            .getJSONArray("About");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        model = new ExploreCatgModel();
                        model.setMemberID(explrObject.getString("iAboutID"));
                        model.setBuissnessName(explrObject
                                .getString("vAboutTitle"));
                        model.setBusinessDescription(explrObject
                                .getString("vAboutDescription"));
                        model.setImage1(explrObject.getString("vImage1"));
                        model.setImage2(explrObject.getString("vImage2"));
                        model.setImage3(explrObject.getString("vImage3"));
                        model.setImage4(explrObject.getString("vImage4"));
                        model.setImage5(explrObject.getString("vImage5"));
                        arrayList.add(model);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

set adapter in litview.

AboutAdapter aboutAdapter = new AboutAdapter(AboutActivity.this, arrayList);
                    listView.setAdapter(aboutAdapter);

**AboutAdapter calss**

```
 public class AboutAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private Context mcontext;
        private ArrayList<RedemptionResult> arrayList;

        public AboutAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RedemptionResult> arrayList) {
            this.mcontext = context;
            this.arrayList= arrayList;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public class Holder {
            TextView txtname;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;
            Holder holder;
            if (vi == null) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_aboutlist, null);
                holder = new Holder();

                holder.txtname = (TextView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.raw_about_txt_name);


                vi.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (Holder) vi.getTag();
            }

                holder.txtname.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());

            return vi;
        }

    }
```

Comment: It is still saying error of return type of getItem()..why?
return type should be something else than object.

Comment: Remove both method.or use baseadpter instead of ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Yet no results being shown, removed both methods..:(
what to do now?

Comment: i post the code for baseadpter and just change ArrayAdapter.Try with above adapter.

Comment: `adapter = new RedemptionListAdapter(context,
        R.layout.redemptionlist,
        redemptionResultResponse.getRedemptionPartners());
      redemptionListView.setAdapter(adapter);` here it is..

Comment: context ?? YourActivityName.this

Comment: changed yet showing error `The constructor RedemptionListAdapter(RedemptionActivity, int, List<RedemptionResult>) is undefined`..

Comment: i have posted my json and json response please take a look if i am missing something in that..
but i am sure there is something wrong in adapter..:(

Comment: it is saying, we need to add something like ` public RedemptionListAdapter(RedemptionActivity redemptionActivity,
   int redemptionlist, List<RedemptionResult> redemptionPartners) {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }` in redemptionadapter..
i have implemented your code it is saying adapter definition error..

Comment: aboutAdapter = new AboutAdapter(AboutActivity.this, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(aboutAdapter);look i set adapter like this.and my AboutAdapter already posted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28007/discussion-between-coder-anonymous-and-moj-ma-ho)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to see the size of list in your constructor of the adapter. It may be a case where the size of the list is 0. Also I don't see any use of

```
private List<RedemptionResult> redemptionResultList = new ArrayList<RedemptionResult>();
```

The redemptionResultList is being set in constructor. So just make the above line to null and then try.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: No size is not 0, i have already confirmed that. There is results in the list.

Comment: I have initiated it to null, still no effect.

Comment: The json response that you have pasted doesn't have redemption_partners as json array. Please check the logs if there is any json exception being displayed. Also, check whether the values are actually being set in the RedemptionResult set method.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you can paste the code of parsing and adding into the list as well.

Answer (score 0):

Beside other issues that may exist in your code, you need to correctly override the following methods in your adapter. Check if they are not overridden.

Code you have posted doesn't seem to override them.

```
public int getCount(){
    return vector.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}
```

Comment: it is throwing error for return type object. I used long, int instead but not working for getItem..

Comment: @Coder anonymous: Ok, I have just got through your code again, you have extended your adatper from ArrayAdapter where as you need to extend it from BaseAdapter instead. Then all the codes will be fine.

Comment: I have implemented as suggested by moj ma ho, not working till now.